# How do you get compiz working with the ATI fglrx 9.6 driver?

Tags: linux, xorg, fglrx

I have Ubuntu 8.10, and I'm trying to get compiz to start. It complains that Xgl, texture_from_pixmap and "Composite extension" are all not present.

It works fine when I only have one monitor enabled.

Here are most of the system details below:

```
# When starting compiz, I get these errors:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ compiz
Checking for Xgl: not present. 
Detected PCI ID for VGA: 
Checking for texture_from_pixmap: not present. 
Trying again with indirect rendering:
Checking for texture_from_pixmap: present. 
Checking for non power of two support: present. 
Checking for Composite extension: not present. 
aborting and using fallback: /usr/bin/metacity 
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0.0".


# lspci
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ lspci | grep ATI
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV610 [Radeon HD 2400 XT]


# fglrxinfo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT
OpenGL version string: 2.1.8087 Release


# Xorg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ dpkg -l xorg
ii  xorg                  1:7.4~5ubuntu3        X.Org X Window System


# /etc/X11/xorg.conf
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1" LeftOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "GLcore"
    Load  "dbe"
    SubSection "extmod"
        Option      "omit xfree86-dga"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "Xinerama" "on"
    Option      "AIGLX"    "on"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option      "Composite" "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection


# glxinfo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.2
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group
client glx vendor string: SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_allocate_memory, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_MESA_swap_frame_usage, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
GLX version: 1.2
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT
OpenGL version string: 2.1.8087 Release
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ATI_meminfo, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_depth_buffer_float, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texgen_reflection, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_KTX_buffer_region, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_WIN_swap_hint, 
    WGL_EXT_swap_control

64 GLX Visuals
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
 id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x23 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x24 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x25 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x26 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x27 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x28 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x29 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2a 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2c 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2d 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2e 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2f 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x30 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x31 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x32 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x33 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x34 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x35 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x36 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x37 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x38 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x39 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x3a 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x3b 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3c 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3d 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3e 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x43 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x44 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x45 24 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x46 24 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4b 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4c 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4d 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4e 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4f 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x50 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x51 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x52 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x53 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x54 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x55 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x56 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x57 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x58 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x59 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x5a 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x5b 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5c 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5d 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5e 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5f 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x60 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x61 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x62 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x63 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x64 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x65 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x66 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6b 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6c 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6d 24 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6e 24 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None

66 GLXFBConfigs:
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
 id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x23  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x24  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x25  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x26  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x27  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x28  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x29  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2a  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2c  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2d  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2e  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x2f  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x30  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x31  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x32  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x33  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x34  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x35  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x36  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x37  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x38  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x39  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x3a  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x3b  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3c  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3d  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x3e  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x43  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x44  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x45  0 tc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x46  0 tc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4b  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4c  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4d  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4e  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x4f  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x50  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x51  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x52  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x53  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x54  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x55  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x56  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x57  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x58  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x59  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x5a  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x5b  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5c  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5d  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5e  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x5f  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x60  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x61  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x62  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x63  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x64  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x65  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x66  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6b  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6c  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6d  0 dc  0 32  0 r  y  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x6e  0 dc  0 32  0 r  .  .  8  8  8  8  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x72  0 dc  0 128  0    y  . 32 32 32 32  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x72  0 dc  0 128  0    .  . 32 32 32 32  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not work. You may need to upgrade to 9.04 and not use fglrx

My experience has been the other way, where 8.10 doing what I wanted, but 9.04 wasn't (specifically, running Boxee on a 3 year old laptop with an ATI graphics card). But then, "they" fixed it, and Boxee now magically runs on my 9.04.

Comment: I tried installing 9.04 and then fglrx, ati and radeon were all hanging when you started X. Here's my question related to that: http://superuser.com/questions/7206/upgrading-ubuntu-to-9-04-breaks-ati-video-card-driver-vesa-and-ati-radeon-driv/9128#9128

Comment: Try disabling fglrx before upgrading. Clean install of 8.10 with no "proprietary" stuff.

What I found was that the network and video customization I had made in 8.04, which survive the upgrade to 8.10, caused problems with the upgrade to 9.04. After a clean install of 9.04, all that tweaking, ndiswrappers, fglrx install stuff wasn't needed any more - the hardware worked.